# Wireless Access Point on a gigabit 802.3 ethernet network

Tags: wireless-networking, lan, wifi-configuration

I have a switched 1 gigabit private lan with about 50 devices on it. Today I added a [UniFI AP](http://www.ubnt.com/unifi#UnifiHardware) to it, so wireless devices will also have access to the network.

My question is:

Is my LAN still 1 gigabit among wired devices? Should I expect a performance hit because of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GigE wired devices wired to the GigE switch connecting to other GigE devices wired to the same switch will continue to be GigE.

Obviously there could be bottlenecks on switch uplinks (assuming you have multiple switches) and you won't get Gig going to the wireless devices.

EDIT: one caveat I just thought of. If you have notebooks that are normally wired, be sure they don't connect to the wireless simultaneously. You'll frequently end up using the wireless NIC for traffic and getting the reduced bandwidth. Don't cross the streams Ray.